# Using JSoup in Android Studio to get text under a class header

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I'm currently using JSoup to read a web page off Indeed.com, and the objective is to get a particular section of the page. I understand using JSoup to get links, etc, but I am struggling to get a body of text under a specific header.

The sample text here would be :

```
<h2 class="jobSectionHeader"><b>What We Are Looking For
</b></h2><div><div><div><div><b>Skills and Requirements</b></div><ul><li>
    Sample requirement 1</li><li>
    Sample requirement 2</li><li>
    Sample requirement 3</li><li>
    Sample requirement 4</li>
</ul></div></div></div>
```

I'm not sure how to use Jsoup to specify the jobSectionHeader area that contains the "qualification" text in it, then get the text under that header. Would I look for a specific class, or certain tags such as div or h2?

Comment: What is your requiered output?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the text under all elements having class as jobSectionHeader, try the below code snippet.This will print the text under that header.

```
String html = "<h2 class="jobSectionHeader"><b>What We Are Looking For
</b></h2><div><div><div><div><b>Skills and Requirements</b></div><ul><li>
    Sample requirement 1</li><li>
    Sample requirement 2</li><li>
    Sample requirement 3</li><li>
    Sample requirement 4</li>
</ul></div></div></div>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements elements = doc.getElementsByClass("jobSectionHeader");
String text = "";
for(Element elem : elements) {
  text += elem.text();
}
Log.d("Text Under jobSectionHeader",text);
```